# Java library unable to import from itself (netbeans, neuroph)

Tags: java, netbeans, neat, neuroph

I have a project in which I use the neuroph library to create neural networks (http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/, version 2.96). I also wanted to use the neat preview library (https://sourceforge.net/projects/neuroph/files/NEAT-preview/, version 0.9), which is a support library for neuroph.

Neuroph core classes are in the package `org.neuroph.`, Neat classes are in `org.neuroph.contrib.neat`.

While I had no problems importing and working with neuroph, when I imported the neat library, it did not recognise its imports from `org.neuroph.core`. in it's own classes (the neuroph core library) and threw an exception when used in the project.

I first tried importing the neat library as a normal library like any other with the described result, afterwards I configured it as a secondary `classpath/source/javadoc` for the original neuroph library. (As you can see in my screenshots), which didn't change anything. I have attached screenshots of the configuration of the library in netbeans, the way the libraries appear in netbeans and the error itself.[The library configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zF9kg.png)  [The library as it appears in netbeans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ki6tG.png)  [The error message in the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYGkv.png)

I have already cleared the netbeans cache and cleaned and rebuilt the project several times with no improvement.

Comment: The NEAT library is over 10 years old, and its README.txt states that it contains **neuroph-core-2.3**. However, you also have **neuroph-core-2.96.jar** on your classpath, so it's not surprising that you have problems. Perhaps try having either version 2.3 or version 2.96 on the classpath, but not both?